# How can I send to grep the search patterns through xargs after using awk?

Tags: linux

How  can I send to grep the search patterns through  xargs after  using awk?

```
awk -F”:” '($5 < 400) {print $1}' file1.txt | xargs grep  file2.txt
```

The output I’m getting is  this one:

```
No such file or directory
```

Thank you for  your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can  use  the  following command to pass  the `awk` results  as    arguments   for `grep` to  search them in the  second file

```
awk -F: '($5 < 400) {print $1}'  file1.txt | xargs -I {} -0 grep "{}" file2.txt
```

Let me  know if this  help you Best regards